# How can this SQL query possibly INSERT duplicate values into the database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, indexing

Background: This is for a Ruby on Rails web application. I have a background job which downloads recent posts from Facebook and inserts them into the database. I'm using hand-coded SQL for performance. The RDBMS is PostgreSQL (on Heroku).

The table is called "posts". I have a unique index on the combination of `posts.uid` and `posts.contact_id`. In the SQL, I use a WHERE condition to filter out `uid`-`contact_id` combinations which are already in the table, but even so, I am getting the following error:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PGError: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_posts_on_uid_and_contact_id"`

Without further ado, here is the (dynamic) SQL:

```
INSERT INTO posts 
(message,contact_id,date,uid,created_at,updated_at,source,is_event)
SELECT  
    t.msg,
    contacts.id, 
    t.date,
    t.uid,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'facebook',
    FALSE
FROM contacts, 
(VALUES #{posts.map { |post| "(E'#{post['message'].escape_singles}','#
 {post['uid']}',DATE '#{format_date(post['time'])}',#{post['status_id']})" }.join(", ")}) AS      
 t (msg,fb_id,date,uid)
WHERE contacts.fb_id = t.fb_id 
AND (NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT * FROM posts 
           WHERE posts.uid = t.uid 
           AND posts.contact_id = contacts.id));
```

Shouldn't the NOT EXISTS condition prevent this from happening?

Comment: What does your data look like if you just run everything from the select clause on? Is that returning duplicate data?

Comment: This will take less than 2 minutes to test, seeing that you already have a database and the query ready. What are you really asking? Have you tested it? Doesn't it work?

Comment: Doug R and BD, excellent suggestions. I'm going to try. KristianAntonsen, I'm not sure if you read the entire question, but yes, I have tested, and I am getting a "unique constraint violated" error. I couldn't see how that would possibly happen (but it's possible that the other 2 commenters may have pointed it out).

Comment: And @JNK, thanks for the edit. Next time I will do the same myself.

Comment: @AlexD - no problem, removing the scrolls make it a lot easier to scan

Comment: @DougR, you nailed it, many thanks. Please post your answer and I will accept+upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select query is returning duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

check for nulls values.

I assume the unique index `"index_posts_on_uid_and_contact_id"` is not the PK so it will accept nulls. If one of the fields on the

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
           WHERE posts.uid = t.uid 
           AND posts.contact_id = contacts.id
```

query is null the exists will return false and duplicated data may be inserted.

Also, I would do `select 1` instead of `select *`. I think its better

I would do

```
WHERE (contacts.fb_id = t.fb_id) and (t.uid is not null) and  (contacts.id is not null)
```

Comment: Is `select 1` faster than `select *` when used in a subquery like this? Won't the RDBMS' query optimizer see that the subquery is being used in an EXISTS clause and optimize it?

Comment: I don't know! It would make sense if it did, of course, but just to be save I always do select 1 when checking "exists". FYI, that's why I said "I think", because I'm not sure

Comment: +1 for the tip on `select 1`. The accept goes to @DougR, though, if he actually posts his answer.

Comment: so it was returning duplicate data?

Comment: Yes, there were duplicates in the array which I was using to dynamically generate the VALUES clause.